# jquery ajax: upload file to c# handler

Tags: c#, json, upload, handler

I want to know if its possible to send a file to a generic handler in c#, and generate some kind of response. For example: post a .txt file to the handler. The handler check if a textfile is submitted and then converts it to json as response. Hope you get the idea. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your handler like this:

```
public class FileUploadHandler : IHttpHandler 
{
    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) 
    {
        HttpResponse response = context.Response;

        foreach (string file in context.Request.Files)  
        {  
           HttpPostedFile hpf = context.Request.Files[file] as HttpPostedFile;  
           if (hpf.ContentLength == 0)  
              continue; 
           //DO SOMETHING WITH FILE.
        }

        //RETURN ANY RESPONSE USING response OBJECT
    }

    public bool IsReusable 
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

for `Request.Files` stuff read [Scott Hanselman's this post](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ABackToBasicsCaseStudyImplementingHTTPFileUploadWithASPNETMVCIncludingTestsAndMocks.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're talking about creating a [web service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service). This tutorial might be a good starting point: http://www.dotnetperls.com/ashx

The basic idea is that you'll create your handler function within a .ashx file, pass it your file information (textfile) via an HTTP POST request, and then write whatever JSON you want to the response object.

Comment: "pass it your file information (textfile) via an HTTP POST request". So i upload the file to the server -> send data from file to handler via a HttpWebRequest -> handler generates json?

Comment: Yep, I think we're on the same page. When you've uploaded the file to the server (your target being yourservice.ashx) you can access the file as a System.Web.HttpPostedFile object. It's stored in the 'Files' collection attribute of your HttpWebRequest object. When you're ready to write your response, put your desired JSON in the Response.Write() function.